# Scanner input issue

Tags: java, input, magic-square

How do I take in input from a user from a scanner, then put that input into a 2D Array. This is what I have but I dont think it is right:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [][] a = new int[row][col];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integers: ");
    while (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        int a[][] = in.nextInt();
        a [row][col] = temp;
        temp = scan.nextInt();
    }
    Square.check(temp);
}
```

What I am trying to do is create a 2D array and create a magic Square. I have the boolean part figured out, I just need help with inputting users sequence of numbers into the array so the boolean methods can test the numbers. All help greatly appreciated

Comment: First thing you need to look at is your row and col variables.  You never increment them so everything is going to get put into the array at the same location.  For example if your square is 3x3 your first three input would go into a[0][0], a[0][1] and a[0][2] so you need to increment your col variable.

Comment: You have error line 5. You're creating scanner second time. Than on line 10 you're using variable thats not created. On line 9 you're adding value to array like in php, but here you dont have specified array length and index...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe your code will work how you want it to. If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's what I would do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [][] a = new int[row][col];

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter integer for row " + i + " col " + j + ": ");
            a[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    // Create your square here with the array
}
```

In the loops, `i` is the current row number and `j` is the current column number. It will ask the user for every row/column combination.

Comment: You still need to declare and initialize row and col.

Comment: @Austin Heerwagen what im trying to do is ask a user for an input of n^2 values to check and see if what they inputted was a magic square. I dont believe you're line 6 asks for that? Unless im not understanding the code, Im very new to java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in order to enter all number at the same time :

```
int [][] a = new int[3][3];
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integers: ");
int row=0,col=0;
while (in.hasNextInt())
{
     a [row][col++] = in.nextInt();
     if(col>=3){
         col=0;
         row++;
     }
     if(row>=3)break;
}
```

Then you can enter :

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

to fill your array.

Comment: but wouldnt this will only make it 3x3?

Comment: I've put static value in order to give you an intelligible example. You can replace the **3** everywhere by the size you want. If you don't know the size of the array user will insert, ask them first in the console using something like :  `Console c = new Console(); int tabSize=Integer.parseInt(c.readLine("Array size :"));`

Comment: can i put row and col when i initialize the array: 'int [][] a = new int[3][3];' and set row and col = 0 then when the user inputs a number it becomes n x n.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question... If you use my code in above comment, you can initialize your array with `int [][] a = new int[tabSize][tabSize]`. When i use `int row=0,col=0;` I just init new temp var in order to fill the array, putting integers at the right index.

Comment: it says constructor Console is not visible

Comment: I've made a mistake in my previous post, use `Console c = System.console();` Sorry I've write it fast and I've init it as a classic object....